# Borrar texto Timestamp

Tags: python

quiero hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
hola=pd.pivot_table(ahumada_concat,index='ID_local',columns='FECHA',values=['STOCK','PRECIO'],aggfunc='count')
```

Cuando ejecuto el anterior código, me sale una pivot table de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, cuando traspaso esta pivot table a dataframe, usando el código:

```
hola= pd.DataFrame(hola.to_records())
```

El DF me sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para la fecha he utilizado estos códigos, ya que anteriormente también me salía el timestamp en la pivot table

```
final=len(ahumada_concat)
fecha=(ahumada_concat['FECHA'].max()).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
ayer=(ahumada_concat['FECHA'].max()- datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Me gustaría poder eliminar el formato de timestamp, y que salga la fecha como en la pivot table.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una aclaración primero, `hola` (la salida de `pandas.pivot_table`) ya es un DataFrame con un MultiIndex como columnas. Lo que consigues con `pandas.DataFaame.to_records` es indirectamente aplanar este multiindex.

Una solución mucho más simple y eficiente es simplemente renombrar las columnas. Vamos a partir de un ejemplo basado en lo que muestras:

```
import io
import pandas as pd


data = io.StringIO("""\n
 ID_local   STOCK   PRECIO        FECHA
F-001-001     0.0   95.0   2020-03-23
F-001-001     2.0   99.0   2020-03-24
F-001-002     3.0   82.9   2020-03-23
F-001-002     2.0   88.9   2020-03-24
""")

ahumada_concat = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+", engine='python', parse_dates=["FECHA"])
```

> ```
> >>> ahumada_concat
>
>     ID_local  STOCK  PRECIO      FECHA
> 0  F-001-001    0.0    95.0 2020-03-23
> 1  F-001-001    2.0    99.0 2020-03-24
> 2  F-001-002    3.0    82.9 2020-03-23
> 3  F-001-002    2.0    88.9 2020-03-24
> ```

Ahora podemos pivotar:

```
hola = pd.pivot_table(
    ahumada_concat, index='ID_local', columns='FECHA',
    values=['STOCK','PRECIO'], aggfunc='count'
    )
```

> ```
> >>> hola
>
>               PRECIO                 STOCK           
> FECHA     2020-03-23 2020-03-24 2020-03-23 2020-03-24
> ID_local                                             
> F-001-001          1          1          1          1
> F-001-002          1          1          1          1
>
> >>> hola.columns
>
> MultiIndex([('PRECIO', '2020-03-23'),
>             ('PRECIO', '2020-03-24'),
>             ( 'STOCK', '2020-03-23'),
>             ( 'STOCK', '2020-03-24')],
>            names=[None, 'FECHA'])
> ```

Podemos aplanar este MultiIndex simplemente con:

```
hola.columns = [f"{name}_{date.date()}" for name, date in hola.columns.values]
```

> ```
> >>> hola
>
>            PRECIO_2020-03-23  PRECIO_2020-03-24  STOCK_2020-03-23  STOCK_2020-03-24
> ID_local                                                                           
> F-001-001                  1                  1                 1                 1
> F-001-002                  1                  1                 1                 1
>
> >>> hola.columns
>
> Index(['PRECIO_2020-03-23', 'PRECIO_2020-03-24', 'STOCK_2020-03-23', 'STOCK_2020-03-24'], dtype='object')
>            PRECIO_2020-03-23  PRECIO_2020-03-24  STOCK_2020-03-23  STOCK_2020-03-24
> ```

Puedes darle el formato que quieras a la cadena, en este caso simplemente uso un subrayado para separar el nombre de la fecha.  Si deseas que cada cadena se siga identificando con una tupla, puedes hacer:

```
hola.columns = [(name, str(date.date())) for name, date in hola.columns.values]
```

> ```
> >>> hola
>            (PRECIO, 2020-03-23)  (PRECIO, 2020-03-24)  (STOCK, 2020-03-23)  (STOCK, 2020-03-24)
> ID_local                                                                                       
> F-001-001                     1                     1                    1                    1
> F-001-002                     1                     1                    1                    1
> ```

Si quieres cambiar el formato de la fecha usa `strftime` tal como muestras en tu pregunta:

```
hola.columns = [f"{name}_{date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}" for name, date in hola.columns.values]
```

Comment: Muchas pero muchas gracias FJSevilla, me has salvado nuevamente.